# sort() with a cascade it works but using map() doesn't work and printing list show same thing again

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart when I use sort() with a cascade it works but using map() doesn't work and the printing list returns the same thing again. Why?

```
 void main(){
        list<dynamic> list= [4,1,3,2]..sort();
        print(list);  //outputs [1,2,3,4]

        var list1= [4,1,3,2]..map((e)=>e+1);
        print(list1); //again outputs [1,2,3,4] 
       }
```

Comment: *"In dart when I use sort() with a cascade it works but using map() dosen't work and printing list returns same thing again.Why?"* - because `sort` modifies the list itself, while `map` creates an new `Iterable`

Comment: Ok thank you,so is it like it tries to return a new object but due to cascade it returns the receiver itself?

Comment: You can use dart.pad to test your code. If you do so, you´ll see that the outputs are not identical! ( list = [1, 2, 3, 4] whereas list1 = [4, 1, 3, 2])

Comment: sorry,yes it outputs still same thing though [4,1,3,2] ,I hope you get what I am trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consult the dart documentation, you can find the following example of how the [sort()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html) method works in detail. In your example you used the `cascading operator` to discard the result of `sort()`, which is `void`, and instead return the `original receiver`, the `list`, which you then conveniently store back into the variable. Consequently, the first output prints the sorted list, as expected.

The `map method`, as you can read [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html), will **return a new lazy Iterable** with elements that are created by calling toElement on each element of this Iterable in iteration order. This **result is now discarded by the cascade operator** and instead the original receiver will be returned.

And here is the problem, whereas the **sort method modified the original list**, which then is returned by the cascade operator (as desired), the map method will create a new Iterbale, which due to the cascade operator will be discarded. Instead the original receiver (the un-modified list) will be returned, it still prints the un-modified list.